# have to save UITextfield's value to the NSUserDefault and then send this value to server

Tags: objective-c

i am trying this code .i jst want to save the value to NSUserDefault,trying to hold the value of NSUserDefault to local var val1, and later on have to send this value val1 to server, but when i run build the application ,username = null appears... m in big trouble..plzzzz help me out....alternate code would be apprecaited.....Thanx in advance

NSUserDefaults *username = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[username setObject:utextFieldNormal.text forKey:@"username"];

```
//NSLog(@"username:%@",utextFieldNormal.text);

NSString *val1= [username valueForKey:@"username "];

NSLog(@"username:%@",val1);
```

[username synchronize]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[username valueForKey:@"username "];
```

You've seen the space there? `@"username " != @"username"`. Maybe that's the source of your problem. And you should use `objectForKey` instead of `valueForKey`.